# Flutter application loads image in emulator (edge) but not on device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, camera

Currently working on a flutter application.
Here is the problem: when i click on the camera icon, i can take a photo. In the popup dialog, i can push the "Toevoegen" (_handlePhotoAdded,) button which adds the image to the slideshow. This all works fine when i run the app in my browser (edge), but when i build an APK, the app doesn't add the images to the slideshow on my tablet. What could be the problem? I uploaded relevant pieces of the code.

This is the dialoge.dart:
https://codefile.io/f/121I0osOEE

This is the checklist02.dart (here is the slideshow): https://codefile.io/f/JZ1WtaJLBu

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Wiljan